# ¿Cómo puede ser que se escuche un tono de 40kHz?

Tags: matlab

mi pregunta es relacionada con el siguiente código de Matlab:

```
Fs = 100*10^3; %Frecuencia de muestreo para que cumpla el teorema de Nyquist
Ts = 1/Fs;
t = 0:Ts:1;  %vector de tiempos de la señal

F = 40000;   %frecuencia de la señal
s = A*cos(2*pi*F.*t+theta);
soundsc(s,Fs)  %reproduzco el sonido con frecuencia de muestreo Fs
```

Mi problema es que sí se escucha el tono que da, y no debería puesto que solo podemos escuchar hasta 20kHz. Además, si pongo una frecuencia por debajo de 20Hz, que tampoco se escucha si se comporta correctamente y no se escucha.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Tiendo a pensar que esto es un problema del hardware que utilizas de salida para el sonido. Hay que tener en cuenta que los altavoces y la circuiteria de sonido afectan a la señal. Como curiosidad mira https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altavoz_piezoeléctrico, son los altavoces más comunes y en frecuencias bajas no son capaces de emitir sonido, y en frecuencias altas responden muy bien

Answer (score 0):

Probe tu código y no tuve problema para oírlo. Probando con F= 20, 440, 1000, 12000 y en 40000 ya no se oía como se esperaría.

No utilice Theta, podrías revisar theta, lo tienes en grados y no en radianes. Y utilize Amplitud de 1.

De igual forma intenta utilizar la función `sound`, en lugar de `soundsc` a ver si tienes respuesta. (Yo utilize `sound`).

```
Fs = 100*10^3; %Frecuencia de muestreo para que cumpla el teorema de Nyquist
Ts = 1/Fs;
t = 0:Ts:1;  %vector de tiempos de la señal

F = 40000;   %frecuencia de la señal
s = cos(2*pi*F.*t);
sound(s, Fs)  %reproduzco el sonido con frecuencia de muestreo Fs
```